# How can I find out if my desktop program is running on the console?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, remote-desktop, rdp

Part of my application is a Windows Forms (C#) desktop program which will be run on a server. I'd rather not go into the gory details of why this is necessary but let's just take it as read that it is!

When it starts up, I'd like to check whether it's being run on the console (i.e. either physically on the console or RDP with the /console switch) as opposed to just any other RDP session.

Answer (score 0):

This class seems to be intresting: `Process`. That is how you can get a process from a remote computer:

```
Process[] procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("TestApp", "MyServer01");
```

But this works only in the local network. If you need to go over the internet, i would write a small selfhosted web-server with one method, which returns **TRUE** if the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to solve your issue. On starting the application you can install the Mutex with a name prefixed by "Global\". In this way it will be unique throughout the system which should enable you to notice that your application is already running on the system.